# Binding single datevalue to DatePicker and TimePicker

Tags: sapui5

sap.m.DateTimeInput is deprecated, the doco suggests using sap.m.DatePicker and sap.m.TimePicker instead

> Deprecated since version 1.32.8. Instead, dedicated sap.m.DatePicker
>   and/or sap.m.TimePicker controls should be used.

I can bind a single datevalue to both controls

```
<Label text="Start Date" />
<HBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom">
    <DatePicker dateValue="{VM>/StartDate}" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy">
        <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
        </layoutData>
    </DatePicker>
    <TimePicker dateValue="{'VM>/StartDate'}" width="100%" >
        <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
        </layoutData>
    </TimePicker>
</HBox>
```

however when i change the TimePicker, the date is set to epoch and similarly when i change the DatePicker the time value is reset.

I want to be able change the DatePicker and keep the TimePicker value and similarly change the TimePicker and keep the DatePicker value.

Anyone know how to do this, the only event is change and this appears to be too late.

Comment: Not sure if your model would cater for it, but would it be possible to introduce two new properties (i.e. `VM>/StartDateTimepart` and `VM>/StartDateDatepart`), bind these to the respective controls, and in the respective `change` event set the correct date/time back to the `VM>/StartDate` property by adding the millisecond representation of both StartDateTimepart/StartDateDatepart properties?

Answer (score 2):

managed to get [a simple solution using the change events](http://jsbin.com/mecexi/edit?html,output)

```
onInit: function() {
    var oStartDate = new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00");
    var oData = {
        StartDate: oStartDate
    };
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData), "VM");
    this._oldDateValue = oStartDate;
},

newDate: function(oDate1, oDate2) {
    return new Date(oDate1.getFullYear(), oDate1.getMonth(), oDate1.getDate(), oDate2.getHours(), oDate2.getMinutes(), oDate2.getMilliseconds());
},

onDateChange: function(oEvent) {
    var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
    var oNew = oSource.getDateValue();
    var oDate;
    if (this._oldDateValue !== oNew.getTime()) {
        if (oSource.getMetadata().getName() === "sap.m.DatePicker") {
            oDate = this.newDate(oNew, this._oldDateValue);
        } else {
            oDate = this.newDate(this._oldDateValue, oNew);
        }
        oSource.setProperty("dateValue", oDate, true);
        this._oldDateValue = oDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Despite the fact that you need a global variable, I quite like your solution!

Comment: @Qualiture instead of using that variable, I wonder if there is a simple way to implement datastate to read old value

Comment: You could maybe use the `data` object of the datepicker & timepicker to store the old value (but it's less simpler than using a global variable...) I guess, global variables aren't always *that* bad ;-)

Comment: You have the old value saved in the model, i used it instead of the global object, no need to declare one.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest not to use binding to fix this issue:

```js
<Label text="Start Date" />
<HBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBottom">
    <DatePicker id="date" displayFormat="dd/MM/yyyy">
        <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
        </layoutData>
    </DatePicker>
    <TimePicker id="time" width="100%" >
        <layoutData>
            <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
        </layoutData>
    </TimePicker>
</HBox>
```

and in the controller:

```js
onInit: function(){
    var oData={StartDate: new Date("October 13, 2014 11:13:00")};
    sap.ui.getCore().setModel(new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData), "VM");
},

onAfterRendering: function(){
    var oDate = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("VM").getData().StartDate;
    sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("date")).setDateValue(oDate);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("time")).setDateValue(oDate);
}
```

This way if you update time/date, the other value doesn't change.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/lixudagici/1/edit?html,output) is a working example.